# How can I get the row count as the result instead of the actual records?

Tags: mysql

In the following table I'm attempting to count the total number of records for which the combination of CustomerID and User occur more than once for a given date range.

```
/*
SQLyog Community v12.12 (64 bit)
MySQL - 5.5.40-MariaDB 
*********************************************************************
*/
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

create table `VWAE` (
    `CustomerID` mediumint (6),
    `User` int (11),
    `DemoOrderDate` date 
); 
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('135068','1210','2015-05-27');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('153305','1210','2015-06-03');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('152566','1210','2015-06-04');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('152566','1210','2015-06-05');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('153896','1210','2015-06-05');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('153041','1210','2015-06-08');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('152566','1210','2015-06-08');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('137405','1210','2015-06-11');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('149813','1210','2015-06-15');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('149813','1210','2015-06-16');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('153698','1210','2015-06-17');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('153698','1210','2015-06-19');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('153698','1210','2015-06-22');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('149813','1210','2015-06-22');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('150919','1210','2015-06-23');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('153698','1210','2015-06-23');
insert into `VWAE` (`CustomerID`, `User`, `DemoOrderDate`) values('149813','1210','2015-06-26');


SELECT count(*)
FROM VWAE
WHERE `User` = 1210
AND DemoOrderDate BETWEEN '2015-06-19' AND '2015-06-26'
GROUP BY CustomerID, `User`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The query returns the following two rows which is correct by all means.

```
CustomerID  User  DemoOrderDate  
149813      1210  2015-06-22     
153698      1210  2015-06-19
```

**However, I'm after counting the number or records returned instead of getting the actual rows. How can this be accomplished?**

Just for the record, the above query is a subquery of a much larger query in which I'm calculating totals for various data. I already tried using the query above to create a derived table t1 and then perform a count on it's rows but in my real query, the WHERE `User` = 1210 clause is actually referencing an alias outside the scope of the subquery, resulting to giving the following error:

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'PRF.user_id' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: what do you want to select exactly ?
what should be the result of this query ?

Comment: I want to select the count of rows returned by the query but with the restriction of not using a derived table to accomplish it.

Comment: your query SELECT count(*) FROM VWAE.. will give the count the records and not the actual records.. And SELECT * FROM VWAE... will give the actual records not the count.

Comment: Its a bit hard to imagine what your SQL table and query ( the outer query of this ) looks like .

the query above is working and wont have any problem , but if you cant access to some column in subquery make sure you make correct aliases

Comment: No need for posting the entire query. My only problem is that I need to retrieve the row count instead of the rows.

Comment: @Matarishvan: Select count(*) will return 2 rows not the count. Please use my sample table data to see for yourself.

Comment: the query you posted 

SELECT count(*)
FROM VWAE
WHERE `User` = 1210
AND DemoOrderDate BETWEEN '2015-06-19' AND '2015-06-26'
GROUP BY CustomerID, `User`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

works okay and it does not have problem , 
you have problem with aliases and scope

Comment: Never said it has a problem. Please read my question in bold more carefully, what I need is to get number 2 as a result instead of 2 rows.

Comment: @bikey77: What do you mean by *number 2* ? the second row of the *count* results?

Comment: @bikey77, i have imported your table and pasted your query. You are mentioning COUNT(*) which should obviously return count rather than the actual result.. Try this `select count(*) from vwae` which should give you 17

Comment: The query I've posted "SELECT count(*)
FROM VWAE
WHERE `User` = 1210
AND DemoOrderDate BETWEEN '2015-06-19' AND '2015-06-26'
GROUP BY CustomerID, `User`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1" returns 2 rows. I DONT want 2 rows, I want the NUMBER of rows returned.

Have a look: http://tinypic.com/r/av3ewj/8

Comment: **@bikey77**: I think you just need `select count(*) as total_records from vwae where user = 1210 and demoorderdate between '2015-06-19' and '2015-06-26' group by user`. As you are specifying which `user`, clause `group by` is unceccessary.

Comment: As I state above, I'm attempting to count the total number of records for which the combination of CustomerID and User occur more than once for a given date range. The query you posted does nothing more than a simple count.

Comment: When you include `customerid` in `group by`, obviously output would be multiple rows if those id's differ. And if you still want count of total rows fetched, you can execute `select count(*) from ( your select query here that fetched 2 rows by grouping custid and user ) base_results`

Comment: Already tried this, it's written right after the bold text in my initial post. Results with a 1054 error.